# What is the purpose of rearranging this integration by parts expression?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

In my textbook they give this series of steps:

$${d\over dx}(u(x)v(x))=u'(x)v(x)+u(x)v'(x)$$

Then integrating both sides:

$$u(x)v(x)=\int(u'(x)v(x)+u(x)v'(x))dx$$

*Then* the textbook rearranges the expression, and it only uses the rearranged version throughout the rest of the book (well, at least throughout the rest of the section).

$$\int u(x)v'(x)dx=u(x)v(x)-\int v(x)u'(x)dx$$

It doesn't explain in the book why this is the preferred version. So my question is: Why is it better?

I looked around online and I couldn't find an explanation, perhaps it isn't anywhere because it's a ridiculous question.

Comment: It turns out that this is one of the most useful and fruitful results in calculus. Keep reading and you will see how we can use this idea to evaluate many integrals that are otherwise fearsome. It also turns out that the proofs of many useful theorems use this simple result.

Comment: Funny how the book takes you through the derivation, but fails to make the purpose clear. Does it give worked problems that employ this technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is convenient to use the rearranged form in order to integrate some functions. For example, suppose we are trying to find the antiderivative of $xe^x$. This means we are trying to find $\int xe^x dx$. So, if we take $u=x$ and $v'(x)=e^x$, we get $u'(x)=1$ and $v(x)=e^x$ (ignoring the $+C$ for now), and so:

$\int xe^xdx=xe^x-\int 1\cdot e^xdx=xe^x-\int e^xdx=xe^x-e^x+C$.

Answer (score 1):

It is often written as $\int u dv=uv-\int v du.$ For example $\int x^2 \cos x dx=\int x^2 d\sin x=x^2 \sin x-\int \sin x d(x^2)= x^2 \sin x-\int (\sin x)(2x dx) =$ $x^2 \sin x-\int 2x d(-\cos x)=$ $x^2 \sin x-(2x.(-\cos x)-\int (-\cos x)) d(2x)=$ $x^2 \sin x+2x.\cos x-2\sin x.$